# Show that h is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $X$ be a set, $\mathcal{A}$ and $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$. Let $f,g: X \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm  \infty\}$ be measurable functions and $A \subseteq X$ measurable. Define $h: X \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \pm \infty \}$ by

\begin{equation}
  h(x)=\begin{cases}
    f(x) & \text{if $x\in A$},\\
    g(x) & \text{if $x \notin A$}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Show that h is measurable.

I think that we start by showing that $A \cap h^{-1}(a, \infty] = A \cap f^{-1}(a, \infty] $ and $A^c \cap h^{-1}(a, \infty] = A^c \cap g^{-1}(a, \infty]$. And then show that $h^{-1}(a, \infty]$ is measurable for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier to note that
$$h= f\chi_A + g \chi_{A^c}$$
and then invoke that products and sums of measurable functions remain measurable.

Comment: I forgot to define $A$ and $X$, would this still apply?

Comment: Yes of course. $X$ is just a general measurable space and $A$ is a measurable subset.

Comment: sorry, just wanted to point out that you   could use $\frac{x^n}{n!}\le \frac{x^n}{2^{n-1}}$, and your argument would work OK, perhaps you could undelete your answer

Comment: @orangeskid Thanks for the suggestion! I will implement it! Definitely no need to apologise :) Have a lovely day :)!